# GeoCodeRequest() constructor returns null

Tags: c#, wcf, soap, bing

I'm trying to create a wcf service that consumes Bing's Geocoding soap service. But when ever i try to set init a new GeoCodeRequest using it's constructor it returns a null.
When I call `request.Query = address;`  I get a null value error referring to  `request` .

```
public string RequestLocation(string address)
        {
            const string key = "mybingapplicationId";
            var request = new GeocodeRequest();
            request.Credentials.ApplicationId = key;
            request.Query = address;

            var filters = new ConfidenceFilter[1];
            filters[0] = new ConfidenceFilter { MinimumConfidence = Confidence.High };

            var geocodeOptions = new GeocodeOptions { Filters = filters };

            request.Options = geocodeOptions;

            // Make the geocode request
            var geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
            var geocodeResponse = geocodeService.Geocode(request);

            return geocodeResponse.Results[0].DisplayName;
        }
```

[UnitTest]

```
 [TestMethod()]
        [HostType("ASP.NET")]
        [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\Development\\WcfService1\\WcfService1", "/")]
        [UrlToTest("http://localhost:24842/")]
        [DeploymentItem("WcfService1.dll")]
        public void RequestLocationTest()
        {
            var target = new TestService.BingEngineClient();
            var address = string.Format("1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, {0}, {1}","Washington", "DC"); 
            var expected = string.Empty;
            var actual = target.RequestLocation(address);
            Assert.IsNotNull(actual);
            Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
        }
```

Comment: You seem to be missing the initialization of the Credentials. `request.Credentials = new GeocodeService.Credentials();`

Comment: I assume that you've been through [Creating a Bing Maps Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg650598.aspx)

Comment: Something seems off. Are you sure you're not getting a null reference exception somewhere in the context of calling the getter for the Query property? What happens if you add a (if request == null) throw new Exception right after the constructor call?

Comment: @Rich It's working fine now. Will post update code below.

Comment: @atbyrd I've posted my comments with some additional info below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First the code is missing initialization of the Credentials.

`request.Credentials = new GeocodeService.Credentials();`

When you go through [Creating a Bing Maps Account](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg650598.aspx) you have to use their application to
[Create a Bing Maps Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx) for the specific application in question. Note that this is different from your account key.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public string RequestLocation(string address)
            {

                var request = new GeocodeRequest {Credentials = new Credentials {ApplicationId = _key}, Query = address};
                var filters = new ConfidenceFilter[1];
                filters[0] = new ConfidenceFilter { MinimumConfidence = Confidence.High };

                var geocodeOptions = new GeocodeOptions { Filters = filters };

                request.Options = geocodeOptions;

                // Make the geocode request
                var geocodeService = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
                var geocodeResponse = geocodeService.Geocode(request);

                return string.Format("Longitude:{0},Latitude:{1}", geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Longitude,
                                     geocodeResponse.Results[0].Locations[0].Latitude);
            }
```